# JS Memory Leak: System memory growing but Chrome Debugger showing constant

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks

I've noticed that sometime within the last month, a subtle memory leak has crept into my Vue app, where the system memory dedicated to the browser starts growing. On initial payload, the Chrome process running my application is using about 100MB of memory, which is about what I'd expect. However, as the app runs, the system memory starts growing by about 0.5-1MB/second. Leaving the page up for a long time this can reach gigabytes of memory consumed, which is obviously a problem. So of course I go to the Chrome memory profiler, but here I find something strange. On the "select javascript VM instance" page, I can see a few VMs for my app. However, the memory for none of these is growing, they fluctuate with a sum around 70MB. How is it possible that chrome memory consumption grows when running my app but the JS VMs are not growing?

UPDATE: This only occurs in chrome, no other browser. A chrome bug is unlikely, is it possible it could be something devtools-related where it's caching information?

Comment: Maybe it's not JS VM memory that is growing but something else.

Comment: @Bergi what else could be growing? Isn't my whole app contained in the VMs?

Comment: I'm not certain, but I guess that things like the DOM and graphics memory are not part of the memory managed by the JS engine.

Comment: I am using mapbox GL, it's certainly possible there's a leak there